# Query regarding NVL in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to display department Id, department name, manager id of all departments. If manager id is not available then display 'NA' and give alias name as 'MANAGER_ID'. Sort the result based on department Id. The type of manager_id is number.

```
select
    department_id, department_name, manager_id, NVL(manager_id, 'na') "BONUS_AMT"
from
    departments
order by 1;
```

is my query but the error is ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

NEED HELP!

Comment: what is the type of manager_id?

Comment: the type of manager_id is number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    department_id, department_name, manager_id,
    NVL(cast(manager_id as varchar2(10)), 'na') "BONUS_AMT"
from
    departments
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `NVL` to get a string when a `NUMBER` is `null`. If you need a string result, you need to convert your number to string; for example:

```
SQL> select nvl(x, 'a') from (select 1 x from dual);
select nvl(x, 'a') from (select 1 x from dual)
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid 



SQL> select nvl(to_char(x, '999'), 'a') from (select 1 x from dual);

NVL(TO_CHAR(X,'999'),'A')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1
```